# Detecting if a user has logged out (got no session) using php via JS, and if so - stopping the execution of the remainder of the JS function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to find a way to detect if a user has no session (which can happen in 2 ways - if the sessions expired OR if the user logged out in another browser window/tab) while running specific JS/jQuery functions.
If the user has no session, the function should stop executing at that point (return false).

I tried using AJAX like so:

```
function CheckForSession() {
        var str="chksession=true";

        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chk_session.php",
                data: str,
                cache: false,
                success: function(res){
                    if(res == "0") {
                      alert('Your session has been expired!');
                    }
                }
        });
}
```

chk_session.php is

```
  require('includes/application_top.php');


  $session_test = $_SESSION['customer_id'];
  if($session_test == '') {
    //session expired
      echo "0";
    } else {
    //session not expired
    echo "1";
   }
```

Then I am calling that function inside:

```
jQuery('body').on('click','.cart_icon_div1.active.selected', function(){

        CheckForSession();
    //if the session doesn't exist, stop running this function, else continue to do more cool stuff

    });
```

The problem is that I am unable to get this to work. Frankly, my js/jQuery skills are quite limited.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a callbacky version:

```
function CheckForSession(onLoggedIn, onLoginExpired) {
    var str="chksession=true";

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chk_session.php",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){
                if(res == "0") {
                    onLoginExpired();
                } else {
                    onLoggedIn();
                }
            }
        });
}


jQuery('body').on('click','.cart_icon_div1.active.selected', function(){

    CheckForSession(function() {
        // Do any important session-required stuff here
       }, 
       function() { 
        alert('Your session has been expired!');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Adan Benzan, thanks, it does work stopping the function if not logged in, but it causes variables inside the callback to be undefined, like *var check_attr = jQuery(this).attr('data-checkattr');* is being used by another AJAX call inside the // Do any important session-required stuff here part, and it returns undefined. It was working fine before. Any way to make it work?

Comment: Those variables are almost certainly being defined outside of the scope of wherever you're setting up that click handler.  It's a bit tricky to tell you exactly how to fix it without seeing where they are, but you could move the jquery('body')....  bit into the block where those variables exist, or pass those values into the "onLoggedIn" function.

Comment: now that you can see the full function, suggestion for the best way to implement it? Note that I will need to use the CheckForSession in many other click/change functions, so I don't think passing all the variables from those functions into it is a good idea.

Comment: Hm, this might get a bit tangled -- I might make that "onLoggedIn" function a non-anonymous function that takes exactly what it needs as arguments and pass those in when it's called in CheckForSession, though that might take some rearchitecting.

Comment: Or break the definition of that onLoggedIn callback outside of the jQuery('body') block and into where those definitions exist and pass that in more like: checkForSession(loggedInHandler, function() { alert('...') });  where "loggedInHandler" is a function defined up where you can see the stuff you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97226/discussion-between-creativemind-and-adam-benzan).

Answer (score 1):

A couple things you could do:

- Check login status on page load and have the status ready to go when the user clicks
- pass a callback into CheckForSession which it runs when the server gives a response.

Personally I would go with option 1.

Comment: Thanks. option 1 is not relevant because the issue here is with users that work on the page after load, while their session has expired (or logged off in another tab/window). How would you implement the callback exactly? Could you please provide a detailed example with my code?